# Convert Gif image to NSData

Tags: ios, nsdata, gif

I have a gif image in my photo album. When I use the `UIImagePickerController` to select that image, I need to convert the image to `NSData` for storing.

Earlier, I used

```
NSData *thumbData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 0.5);
```

but it will not work with gif images. `thumbData` will be nil.

1. How can I get `NSData` from the gif image?
2. How can I know that it is a gif image that needs special handing?

Comment: Did you also use UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail); ?

Comment: have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6573869). It may be helpful to you.

Comment: Have solved your problem ?

Answer (score 11):

The key here is to save the GIF file or URL download directly into a NSData instead of making it a UIImage. Bypassing UIImage will let the GIF file keep the animation.

Here is some code to convert a GIF file into NSData:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"gifFileName" ofType: @"gif"];

NSData *gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
```

But in all honesty, you should really consider not using GIF at all.

Answer (score 4):

### Swift

Gif must **not** be in assets.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "loader", ofType: "gif")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
return data
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mattt/AnimatedGIFImageSerialization

```
UIImage *image = ...;
NSData *data = [AnimatedGIFImageSerialization animatedGIFDataWithImage:image
                                                              duration:1.0
                                                             loopCount:1
                                                                 error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Code to coverting .GIF file can converted in NSdata -

```
NSString *pathForFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"myGif" ofType: @"gif"];

NSData *dataOfGif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: pathForFile];

NSLog(@"Data: %@", dataOfGif);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Those who are looking for a swifty answer to this question, here's an extension of UIImage that does the job.

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

extension UIImage {
    func UIImageAnimatedGIFRepresentation(gifDuration: TimeInterval = 0.0, loopCount: Int = 0) throws -> Data {
        let images = self.images ?? [self]
        let frameCount = images.count
        let frameDuration: TimeInterval = gifDuration <= 0.0 ? self.duration / Double(frameCount) : gifDuration / Double(frameCount)
        let frameDelayCentiseconds = Int(lrint(frameDuration * 100))
        let frameProperties = [
            kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: [
                kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime: NSNumber(value: frameDelayCentiseconds)
            ]
        ]

        guard let mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0),
           let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(mutableData, kUTTypeGIF, frameCount, nil) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AnimatedGIFSerializationErrorDomain",
                          code: -1,
                          userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Could not create destination with data."])
        }
        let imageProperties = [
            kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount: NSNumber(value: loopCount)]
        ] as CFDictionary
        CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, imageProperties)
        for image in images {
            if let cgimage = image.cgImage {
                CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgimage, frameProperties as CFDictionary)
            }
        }

        let success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
        if !success {
            throw NSError(domain: "AnimatedGIFSerializationErrorDomain",
                          code: -2,
                          userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Could not finalize image destination"])
        }
        return mutableData as Data
    }
}
```

2. While the above extension will do the job, handling gif from image picker is simpler, here's the implementation in `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` function.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let info = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: info.map {key, value in (key.rawValue, value)})
    if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.referenceURL.rawValue] as? URL, url.pathExtension.lowercased() == "gif" {
       picker.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
       url.getGifImageDataFromAssetUrl(completion: { imageData in
           // Use imageData here.
       })
       return
    }
}
```

with using an extension function in URL

```
import UIKit
import Photos

extension URL {
    func getGifImageDataFromAssetUrl(completion: @escaping(_ imageData: Data?) -> Void) {
        let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [self], options: nil)
        if let image = asset.firstObject {
            PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: image, options: nil) { (imageData, _, _, _) in
                completion(imageData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gives too slow gif animation, i tried different combinations but does not work.

Comment: Did you make sure that the `Data -> UIImage` conversion is not clamping the delay time? According to a few sources, any frame with duration less than 0.05 will be clamped to 0.1

Comment: how can i make sure of that ? can you please guide ? i played with "frameDelayCentiseconds" variable. but nothing, outcome is almost same

Comment: Thks a lot !  This help me to update Gif data then convert to Gif data again.