# Use NSBitmapImageRep transformed Gif

Tags: objective-c

I am a developer from China. I try to use NSBitmap ImageRep to convert GIF images into NSData, but the converted GIF images have no animation, it seems only the first frame. This is my code. I don't know what the problem is. I hope to get your help. Thank you.

```
NSData *gifData = [gifiImage TIFFRepresentation];
NSBitmapImageRep *bitMapRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:gifData];
NSData *data = [bitMapRep representationUsingType:bitmapType properties:nil];
```

Comment: check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748355/convert-gif-image-to-nsdata

Comment: @Nirav Kotecha Thank you. I read the answers carefully, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.