# how to convert jpg to tiff inside my app

Tags: ios, swift2, uiimage, tiff, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I have not been able to find any info on creating a `TIFF` on `iOS` (or converting a jpg or getting a `TIFF` representation from a `UIImage`) in the search engines.

I need to create a `TIFF` image, preferably from my `UIImage` or converting from a jpg representation. I see `PNG` and `JPG` support but nothing for `TIFF` images.

The service I am uploading images to requires `TIFF` (signature capture).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562195/converting-between-multiple-image-formats-in-objective-c

Comment: i want to use this for iPhone app using swift language it would be helpful if you can tell me more about this because i am a beginner

Comment: @HiteshSurani the link you pasted here is specified for macOS

Comment: You can also do for iPhone application.